# Confused about correct way to import packages

Tags: java, package

My directory structure is very simple: in one directory, I have one file called Foo.java and one file called Bar.java

Foo.java:

```
package Foo;

public class Foo {
}
```

Bar.java:

```
import Foo.*;

public class Bar {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Foo foo; // This line breaks compilation

    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

Everything compiles fine without the line `Foo foo`. But when I add it, I get:

```
$ javac Bar.java Foo.java 
Bar.java:5: error: cannot access Foo
    Foo foo;
    ^
  bad class file: ./Foo.class
    class file contains wrong class: Foo.Foo
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
1 error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most Important Thing for this kind of issues is never use same name for different classes, packages and variables, keep uniqueness in it, declare package name as per your project type, class name as per your functionality type and variable name as per your value type, then you will never face this kind of issue anytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac Bar.java Foo.java` , this is plain wrong .`Foo` is in a package named `Foo`(please use a different name to avoid confusion).

you'll have to use `javac -d "path to classes dir here" Foo/Foo.java` and `javac -d "path to classes dir here " Bar.java` .

Answer (score 2):

If both `Foo.java` and `Bar.java` are in the same `Foo` package, you don't need to import `Foo.*` package (this way import static methods and shared constants of Foo class); You just write:

```
package Foo;

public class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo;
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If you have made two different packages: `Foo` for `Foo.java` and `Bar` for `Bar.java`, you write:

```
package Bar;

import Foo.Foo; // or import Foo.*;

public class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo;
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```